# How to turn redis into spark dataset or dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, redis, apache-spark-sql, spark-redis

I am trying to use redis as the source of spark sql, but got stuck with how to transform the rdd. Below are my codes:

```
    RDD<Tuple2<String,String>> rdd1 = rc.fromRedisKV("user:*",3,redisConfig);

    JavaRDD<Row> userRDD  = rdd1.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, Row>(){
        public Row call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(tuple2._2);
            return RowFactory.create(tuple2._2().split(","));
        }
    });

    List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
    structFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField( "name", DataTypes.StringType, true ));
    structFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField( "sex", DataTypes.StringType, false ));
    structFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField( "age", DataTypes.IntegerType, false ));
    StructType structType = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);

    Dataset ds = spark.createDataFrame(userRDD, structType);
    ds.createOrReplaceTempView("user");
    ds.printSchema();

    String sql = "select name, sex, age from user ";

    List<Row> list2 = spark.sql(sql).collectAsList();
```

I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

I have no idea what to do next, please help!

Comment: did you try spark-redis new DF support?
See: https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/releases/tag/v2.3.1-m1

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason: There is nothing wrong with my code, but I need to upload the jar of my application to Spark server.